# What is the difference between androidx.appcompat:appcompat and androidx.core:core jetpack libraries?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

for `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` in [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat)

> Allows access to new APIs on older API versions of the platform (many using Material Design).

and for `androidx.core:core` in [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core)

> Target the latest platform features and APIs while also supporting older devices.

The descriptions for both sound similar. But what is the difference between them? When we should use each one?

Comment: [appcompat](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:appcompat/appcompat/src/)  [core](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:core/core/src/)

Comment: The gist is (I think) that appcompat is ui stuff and core is utils for everything android

Comment: Does it mean that we should always add both to project?